# shell glob pattern trouble

Tags: unix, sh, glob

I'm trying to print out an out the corresponds to an input. The input would be a number and the output would print out the number in english. I am having trouble with the syntax/regular expressions in unix. If I were to run this with an input of 277, there would only be "one-hundred" as output. Where it should be "one-hundred twenty." Is there something wrong with it..? I've looked everywhere and it seems right.

I know it's not complete yet but it is bothering me. Any tips?

```
case "$1" in
1[0-9][0-9]) # 100's
    echo one-hundred
    if [ "$1" == 12[0-9] ]
    then
        echo twenty
    fi
;;
```

Comment: The `case` command globs its patterns as you see. The `test` command (also known as `[`) does not. It appears as if you might be using a less capable shell, what does `echo $SHELL` tell you?

Comment: @msw it shows /bin/bash

Comment: Then @EricRenouf's answer will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex syntax is `=~` not `==` so your if needs to be `[[ "$1" =~ 12[0-9] ]]` though not every shell supports that syntax

Comment: I'm puzzled by the space in `12 [0-9]` but don't have a real computer in front of me.

Comment: The original problem isn't so much that you need to use `=~`, as that `=` in `[ ... ]` doesn't support pattern matching. `[[ $1 = 12[0-9] ]]` would work just as well as `[[ $1 =~ 12[0-9] ]]`. The two are slightly different, however; the pattern is anchored at both ends, while the regular expression is not. The pattern `12[0-9]` is equivalent to the regular expression `^12[0-9]$`.